# Concentrate made of cider apples in the EU or UK?

Tags: cider

I have been googling for that for a while but I can't find what I'm searching for, namely an online store selling concentrate of cider apples, I am referring to the specific varieties used only for cider like Crimson King and similars.

I can find plenty of the normal apple concentrate online and in the supermarket, here in the Netherlands we call it "diksap" ("dik" means thick, LOL), I would like to try getting the flavour of the English cider I can buy bottled or of the Northern Spanish one.

Comment: Do you have a homebrew shop around? They might know?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you'll find a specific off the shelf concentrate since most of the apples will be purchased by the manufacturer.

Your best bet is to do some research, and call local orchards to find what varieties they sell and can juice fresh for you, I find it to be much more satisfying that way.